# Is it unhealthy to drink cold water?

Tags: diet, water, temperature

I've heard it's healthy to drink warm water that is close to (internal) body temperature so that energy doesn't go into warming it up and that it doesn't "shock" the system. Does that mean it's unhealthy to drink cold water? I find it helps me cool down on a hot day.

Comment: This question is off topic, please read the [faq] before posting.

Comment: +1, and Welcome.  Your question would be suited to this proposed site, if you would kindly join it:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Answer (score 2):

Co-signing to what you said. In the hot summer days I would always try to drink a rather cold water in order to cool down. Just how you said the body warms it up so it basically takes away from the body's temperature. It always works well for me.

I also know from my doctor that very cold water will shock your system and from my dentist that it is bad for the teeth's enamel. That's why I try to not abuse it.

Comment: +1, Well answered Arthlete, and welcome to the site.  If you have not done so, please show your support for the nutrition site:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Comment: @Chris I clicked on follow, was that the right thing to do?